# SQL Server query to get data for last two months

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
    DAY(table_A.PaymentDate) as date1 ,
    (CASE 
        WHEN MONTH(table_A.PaymentDate) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
          THEN CAST(SUM(table_A.Total_Amount) As INT) 
          ELSE 0  
     END) AS This_month_CNT, 
    (CASE 
        WHEN MONTH(table_A.PaymentDate) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1 
          THEN CAST(SUM(table_A.Total_Amount) AS INT)  
        ELSE 0  
     END) AS last_month_CNT 
FROM 
    Tbl_Pan_Paymentdetails  table_A 
FULL OUTER JOIN  
    Tbl_Pan_Paymentdetails table_B ON table_A.PaymentDate = table_B.PaymentDate
WHERE 
    YEAR(table_A.PaymentDate) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    AND table_A.PaymentDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY  
    DAY(table_A.PaymentDate),
    MONTH(table_A.PaymentDate) 
ORDER BY 
    DAY(table_A.PaymentDate) ;
```

Comment: I think your question needs more explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: So what's your question and  what is the issue you're facing?

Comment: When you say 'last two months', do you mean last two months from today (i.e. if today was 15 Aug 2015, you're looking for 15 Jun - 15 Aug 2015)? Or do you mean last two full months (1 Jun - 31 Jul 2015)? Because there seems to be some confusion over month/year boundaries in your query, which is making it more difficult to figure out what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand.

```
WHERE YEAR(table_A.PaymentDate) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND
      table_A.PaymentDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETDATE())
```

Here you are (1) comparing the Year elements of your payment date with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, and (2) making sure the payment date is greater than the last 2 months based on `GETDATE()`?

Not sure why you are using both `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `GETDATE()`. Either way, I think the second part of that WHERE statement does what you want.

If the current date is January 31, 2015, your currently logic will not return any records from December 2014. The first part of your where statement is filtering them out. If you really want the last 2 months, remove the following from the WHERE statement

```
YEAR(table_A.PaymentDate) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND
```